# How to implement secure E2EE for a managing App

Tags: web-application, sensitive-data-exposure, end-to-end-encryption

**TL;DR** Is it possible to create an end-to-end encrypted web application where newly created users are able to access data encrypted before their creation?

---

My plan is to develop a (let's call it a Customer-Managing-App). This app should also consider teamwork.

Because Customer-Data belongs to the sensitive data, I would like to implement E2EE (end-to-end encryption)

***What I already did***

I already read a lot about E2EE and also read the articles from Signal.

I also made a few plans for how it could work. But at the time there were always some obstacles. e.g. I had the idea of a hybrid encryption. In detail, I planned to generate:

- a symmetric key for the whole team (this should be used to de/encrypt all of the  sensitive data)
- a key pair for every single user

Because the app should also be accessible over the web, these keys have to be stored on the server side, **BUT**
because this is a big security issue there have to be some precautions. I already thought of this:

- use the password of the user to encrypt the private key before storing it on the server (the password is never known by the server)
- use the public key of the user to encrypt the symmetric key.
- then the symmetric key is only stored encrypted for each user (f.e. for 10 users there are 10 encrypted keys)

---

But now there are some problems coming up.

- **Creating Users** - creating the first-ever user is not really a problem. The first user generates the symmetric key and a key pair, encrypts the private key with his password and the symmetric key with a public key. But now he wants to invite his team colleagues. That means a new user will be created. Now the invited user has to set his custom password. Once he does this, he generates a key-pair for himself. Then he encrypts his private key with his password and stores it into the database. So far so good. but what now? He also needs the symmetric key. But the only one who is capable of knowing this key is the first user...

Okay well, thats bad, and won´t work. But I thought of a fix (until I ran into the next issue):

So, to fix the issue, I have to generate a new symmetric key (I think that´s also the thing that´s happening in chat applications and that's the reason why new members can´t even read old messages). When I generated the new key, I had to encrypt this key with my public key. But this new key is not even capable of doing anything (in a team aspect), so I have to change all existing keys. For the first user, this wouldn´t be even a problem. He can decrypt the old key, use this key to decrypt all of the data and encrypt it with the new key.

**BUT** until this happens, the new user can´t even work on the old data. But since it´s a managing application, he needs to be able to do so.

---

So what am I missing?

Here are my main questions:

1. is it even possible to develop a E2EE managing app?
2. relating to my possible fix - wouldn´t it be a huge performance impact if I have e.g. (**warning - hyperbole**) 1.000.000 customers in the database and related to those customers 10 files for each customer which needs to be decrypted and encrypted again if I add a user or delete a user?
3. are there other possible solutions with a comparable security level?
4. What do you think would be an appropriate level of security for an enterprise-level application storing such sensitive data?

Comment: All members in a team trust each other so they must be given access to the symmetric key that encrypts their customer data. Your actual problem is how to share this key with new members of the team in a stateless manner that is even if existing members are not online, new comers should be able to access the data whenever they sign up.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I thought of a possible solution. f.e. if the existing member is setting a custom temporary password for the new member, then he also could generate the matching encrypted key. And later, when the user logs in with the password (given by the existing member) the new member has to change his password. When he sets the new password the private key will be encrypted again. 

But that would mean, that the most breachable point of the application is now the communication way of the members. And thats something i can´t control.

(Plus its not a very beautiful solution)

Comment: Use [OPAQUE protocol](https://youtu.be/4YntXt1Jobk?si=jiIWurPHtt6tyY6U). Hardware Security Module at server side will store the data encryption key and team members will use OPQUE to register new key or to retrieve the registered key. The only condition is OPAQUE requires the knowledge of shared password which should be shared out of band. As OPAQUE can register new key, you can rotate data encryption key with new shared password whenever any existing member leaves the group.

Comment: Check out how [WhatsApp uses OPAQUE protocol](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp_Security_Encrypted_Backups_Whitepaper.pdf) (pdf) to implement end-to-end encrypted backups.

Comment: Do i understand right? OPAQUE uses a shared password for all users? 
I will watch the vid and read the document later. 

But thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: Yes, it uses a shared password for key exchange.

Comment: Hmm, I think that would be very inconvenient. As well that would mean, that the password has to be changed and all data reenrypted everytime a user leaves the team

Comment: If you are going to allow new members to access existing data, you will have to reencrypt the data with a new key whenever someone leaves the group otherewise they can leak the key to the attacker.

Comment: Yes, that's also quite inconvenient. Currently I couldn't think of a workable solution without some compromises.

Comment: But how do other cloud applications even store such sensible data? Or is it just not E2EE? Is it even necessary to use such a high level of security for an enterprise software I mentioned?

Comment: They encrypt data at server side. They don't make it E2EE. E2EE means only the client should be able to decrypt it. What HSMs can do the most for you is to securely store your data encryption key that the server can't access or see in transit. What's your solution?